# PHP - Simplest Way to Post & Display

Tags: php, html, post, web

Sorry if this has been asked before.
But what is the simplest method to post some text to a site and then display it like on a blog. I don't want it to be a blog, just a textarea, where you can type some text and submit. Like so:

```
<h1>Post</h1>
<form action="post.php" method="POST">
    <textarea name="texty" id="texta" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Post!"/>
</form>
```

Can someone help me with the PHP to transfer that information and post it on the site so that it stays there like a blog. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just :

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['texty'])){
 echo htmlentities($_POST['texty'])
}
?>
```

And look Mysql ;) 
INSERT INTO...

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look how to do it with MySQL too.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `POST` data via `$_POST[]` see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php.

To store it permanently you need to use a data store, one would be a database such as MySQL. That's another chapter though and is not in the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1):

i think u can send the form by ajax : $('form').ajaxForm({url: 'respond.php', success:function(data){ $('.blog').append(data)}})  and in respond.php u should insert the input into database like => if(isset($_POST['submit']) and !empty($_POST['texty'])){ $input  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']); $input = htmlentities($input);  now u can insert $insert  = mysql_query("insert into tablename(input) values('{$input}') "); if($insert){ echo $input ; } i am new in php. so i think this works